# regex parar caso o charactere logo em seguida seja outro

Tags: regex

**Seguinte: Tenho esse texto para exemplo**

`aluno['ACERTOS_ATV2_D2'] >5.5 & aluno['IDADE'] >24.5 & aluno['PROVA1_D2P'] 
 <0.5  & aluno['ASSISTIU_AULA_1_D2'] <0.5 & aluno['FEZ_FORUM_D2SIM'] > 0.5`

---

Preciso fazer um regex que mude esse parte em engrito. por exemplo, esse

`aluno['PROVA1_D2P'] <0.5** deve ficar **aluno['PROVA1_D2'] != 'P'** (aqui é != 
 pois o simbolo é de menor <)` e o  `aluno['FEZ_FORUM_D2SIM'] > 0.5** deve ficar aluno['FEZ_FORUM_D2'] == 'SIM'** (aque é == pois o simbolo é >)`

---

Estou fazendo 2 regex, um para cada simbolo de > <. Não há problemas em fazer 2x. A primeira substituição funciona, mas quando eu vou fazer a segunda, ele da problema.

**Meu regex está assim:**

```
/(PROVA1_D2|FEZ_FORUM_D2)(.*?)\]\s\<\d\.\d/g
o replace está $1'] == '$2
```

---

`aluno['ACERTOS_ATV2_D2'] >5.5 & aluno['IDADE'] >24.5 & aluno['**PROVA1_D2'] != 'P'**  & aluno['ASSISTIU_AULA_1_D2'] <0.5 & aluno['FEZ_FORUM_D2SIM'] >0.5`

---

Até aqui ok, tudo certo, mas quando vou fazer a segunda parte (que é no meu caso é só inverte no regex o < por >) o match que ele faz é esse

`aluno['ACERTOS_ATV2_D2'] >5.5 & aluno['IDADE'] >24.5 & aluno['**PROVA1_D2'] != 'P'  & aluno['ASSISTIU_AULA_1_D2'] <0.5 & aluno['FEZ_FORUM_D2SIM'] >0.5**`

---

Deveria ser esse

`aluno['ACERTOS_ATV2_D2'] >5.5 & aluno['IDADE'] >24.5 & aluno['PROVA1_D2'] != 'P'  & aluno['ASSISTIU_AULA_1_D2'] <0.5 & aluno['**FEZ_FORUM_D2SIM'] >0.5`

Lembrando que é tudo em uma linha esse texto, é que fica meio grande e acaba quebrando aqui

EDIT 1:

Achei que tava tudo certo o que tinha feito na minha própria resposta, mas acabei de encontrar um probleminha.

```
((PROVA1_D2|FEZ_FORUM_D2|REGIAO)(\w+))(.*?)\]\s\>\d\.\d
```

esse regex está dando esse match (entre os asteriscos)

```
aluno['*********REGIAOsudeste'] <0.5 & aluno['ANOCONCL_2G'] >2015.5 & aluno['IDADE'] <42.5 & aluno['ACERTOS_ATV3_D1'] <2.5 & aluno['BOLSA'] >0.2*************5 & aluno['PROVA1_D2P'] <0.5 & aluno['FEZ_FORUM_D2SIM'] <0.5
```

E na verdade eu queria que não desse match nenhum, já que no regex está o simbolo de maior (>), não o menor (<)! O match só aconteceria com o simbolo de menor "<"

Se precisar, eu tenho salvo aqui a situação [REGEX](https://regexr.com/3ijmr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar assim

```
((PROVA1_D2|FEZ_FORUM_D2|REGIAO)(\w+))\'\]\s(?!\<)\>\d{1}\.\d{1,2}
```

E o regex assim

```
$2'] == '$3'
```